# Finding pdf of function of random variables

Tags: probability, density-function, bivariate-distributions

Given the problem:

> X and Y are independent and uniform in the interval (0,a). Find the p.d.f of $\frac{y}{x+y}$

Currently I have solved it such that

$$F_z(z) = P(Z \le z) = P\{\frac{Y}{X+Y} \le z \}$$
$$ = P\{\frac{X}{Y} \ge \frac{1}{z}-1\} = 1 - P\{\frac{X}{Y}\le\frac{1-z}{z}\}$$
$$= \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}(\frac{z}{1-z}),  & 0 \le z \le 1/2 \\
1-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1-z}{z}), & 1/2 \le z \le 1
\end{cases}$$

However, the answer to the problem comes out to:

$$ f_z(z) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2(1-z)^2},  & 0 \le z \le 1/2 \\
\frac{1}{2z^2}, & 1/2 \le z \le 1
\end{cases}$$

I can't figure out what I need to do to get to that last step to get the given answer. It's obviously more than some simple algebra with my answer. Would someone be able to help? Thank you so much for your help in advanced!

Comment: For the sake of brevity I purposely skipped some of the integration steps. Let me know if you need any clarification

Comment: You computed the CDF and the answer given to you provides the PDF. Exercise: Differentiating your CDF yields the same PDF.